# add eventlistener "load" after the event has been fired

Tags: javascript, event-listener

what happens when I add an Eventlistener of type "load" (with this I mean  `addEventListener("load", function(event){...})`) after the event has been fired (e.g. I am loading a google maps api in the beginning of my document than I am doning some php request and after that I am adding the listener to decide whether the google-api script has loaded). I would like the EventListener to invoke the callback in the case the script has already loaded. Does this happen by default?

My code is this

html-doc:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&callback&signed_in=true&callback=RoadtripsTable.drawRoadtripsOnMap"async defer></script>
```

JS-doc:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../PHP/RoadtripsTable.php",
    data: ({
    fnChoice: "listRoadtrips"
}),
    success: function(result){
             head.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
                 if (event.target.nodeName === "SCRIPT")
                 {
                 /*now I would like to call the callback of the script tag in html*/ drawRoadtripsOnMap(); /* but what happens when the script was alread loaded?*/
                 }
             }, true);

             }
});
```

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view you need to switch to `Promises`, because the traditional way of handling the event will not fire once the event has already occurred but if you are using promises in your code then **Promise** gives you flexibility to execute your code(which you scheduled to execute after/on event fire like callback) even if the event has already occurred.

[Javascript Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

Comment: @Nighel Yup! it works but I love promises and it's better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you just need to check if google maps is loaded

```
if (google && google.maps) {
    // google maps is loaded
}
```